# Storing manipulated ImageData into imageObject. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I want to load an image, copy it e.g. 2 times, and manipulate the other 2 images. Somehow I want to do some "post-processing" stuff with the two clones. I DON'T want to get canvas parts and manipulate them. I am programming a realtime 2D game and it would be madness to manipulate every image within every frame.
Many of the solutions I found were just "cutting" parts from the canvas, dealing with them and writing them back onto the canvas. But I want to have the manipulated images stored in imageObjects to be able to directly draw them as if they were the "real" image.

Comment: `function manipulate_images()
{
//do the magic
}`

Seriously,what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canvas is still the best way of manipulating images. Canvas slices that you get via `context.getImageData()` can be painted back via `context.putImageData()` (see [Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)) so I don't see a real advantage of converting image data into images. However, if you prefer a "real" image object, you can use [`canvas.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Methods) and create an image object with this URL. Something along these lines:

```js
// Create temporary canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("width", imageData.width);
canvas.setAttribute("height", imageData.height);

// Put image data into canvas
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

// Extract canvas data into an image object
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
image.onload = function() {alert("Image object can be used")};
```